# Batch code to read text file

Tags: batch-file, filereader

I have batch file  which write the list of all available drives in a text file and
another batch file to read the contents in that text file (skips first line)

The code for drive list is:

```
wmic logicaldisk get name> "abc.txt
```

The code  that is used to read the text file is:

```
FOR /F "skip=1" %%m IN (abc.txt) DO (echo %%m)
```

The reader batch only will works only if the file is manually created, why??

Need some solutions, please help!

Comment: There is no need for append mode `>>` redirection. Normal `>` works fine in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As miltonb stated, WMIC output is in unicode UTF-16 format with BOM.

FOR /F does not like unicode. You can use TYPE to transform the unicode into ANSI. Note that the IN() clause is enclosed in single quotes, so FOR /F reads the output of the command instead of a file.

```
FOR /F "skip=1" %%m IN ('type abc.txt') DO (echo %%m)
```

---

**EDIT**

It is possible to put your WMIC command directly within a FOR /F IN() clause, and completely eliminate the need for a temporary file.

Even though FOR /F cannot read a unicode file, it can process the unicode output of WMIC directly. Unfortunately, it introduces an artifact of an extra carriage return appended to each line (I have no idea why). This can cause parsing problems. There are multiple ways to handle the issue. My favorite is to use one extra FOR /F loop to strip the terminating carriage return from each line.

Note that the 2nd FOR /F uses double quotes in the IN() clause to cause it to read the string.

```
for /f "skip=1" %%A in ('wmic logicaldisk get name') do for /f %%B in ("%%A") do echo %%B
```

Comment: That is a cool trick with the '' dbenham, I did not know that one.

Comment: How can we make the code to always point towards the last line(skip all the other lines )

Comment: @user2765512 - The simplest solution is to have the FOR /F loop set a variable to equal the value of each line. The last line wins :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the wmic is outputing UTF-16 format which is indicated by the FF FE at the start of the file [(Hex Dump Tool)](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm).  The command FOR can not understand the Unicode format and is not finding anything.

You will need an intermediate step to convert the abc.txt into plain text.  This explains why when you manually create in plain text format the file it works as expected.  Add the following to your second batch file which will do the conversion.

```
    TYPE abc.txt > abcplain.txt
    FOR /F "skip=1" %%m IN (abcplain.txt) DO (echo %%m)
```